# apache phoenix query using dynamic columns returns no record

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a phoenix table over existing HBase table created like:

```
CREATE TABLE "t" ("rowkey" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY)
```

table `t` is an existing HBase table with several other columns all in one column family `cf`.

Now, when I run the following query on phoenix, I get no record:

```
SELECT * FROM "t" ("c1" VARCHAR, "c2" VARCHAR, "c3" VARCHAR) LIMIT 5.
```

Moreover, when I try to specify the column family i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM "t" ("cf"."c1" VARCHAR, "cf"."c2" VARCHAR, "cf"."c3" VARCHAR) LIMIT 5.
```

It gives error: `"cf".null` is not defined.

Is the syntax I am using correct? and any ideas where the problem can be.

ps: When I am use VIEWS, there is no issue.

Comment: What phoenix version are you using?

Comment: Phoenix version is 4.5, and hbase version 1.0.0.